# How to to solve why this KeyError that is appearing in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I'm using Pandas to process the Dataframe, I need to use the `Date` column to create additional columns:

I have filtered the `Date` column to get 2022/2021 information only using:

`df = df.loc[df["Date"].between("2022", "2021")]`

Currently I have:

| Date | Type | Initial | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Bin | S | 5 |
| 2022 | Bin | S | 6 |
| 2022 | Bin | S | 9 |
| 2021 | Bin | B | 5 |
| 2021 | Bin | B | 7 |
| 2021 | Bin | B | 0 |

I am currently trying to get the following output:

| Type | 2022 | 2021 | Initial | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bin | 20 | 12 | S/B | 8 |

Following the process to create the bottom table, I have come across the following error

```
df = df.loc[df["Date"].between("2022", "2021")]
dfx = df.groupby(['Type ','Date ']).agg({'Initial ':lambda x: '/'.join([str(r) for r in x.unique()]),'Number':'sum'}).reset_index()
dfy = dfx.pivot(index=['Type ','Initial '], columns='Date ', values='Number').reset_index()
```

but I keep receiving the following error message:

```
  raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Date'
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error but I would definitely take all the trailing spaces out of column names wherever they are - this is just a recipe for confusion and bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyError: 'Date'` doesn't have a space in it.  this is the only line I see where `Data` doesn't have a trailing space.

```
df = df.loc[df["Date"].between("2022", "2021")]
```

Try adding a trailing space and see what happens:

```
df = df.loc[df["Date "].between("2022", "2021")]
```

Like @topsail says, trailing spaces in column names are a recipe for errors,